# Web services = best way for web and mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, ajax, rest

I want to create a web app (**full AJAX**), iOS and Android **NATIVE** applications with a MySQL database.

I only know web services (RESTfull) but is it the best solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes RESTFULL is the best way to create your api, and communicate with JSON with all your front apps web android and ios.